# Can large scale fixed format data qualify as big data?

Tags: relational-database, bigdata

In a hypothetical scenario, there are hundreds of machines located worldwide.
All of them generate housekeeping data, logs, records 24x7.
One possible use of this data is to generate various kind of reports.

Entire of this data generated is having a fixed format, and can very well be defined using corresponding relational schema.

*Does that qualify as big data merely because of its huge extent ?*

*How to choose between relational or NoSQL solution for this kind of problem ?*

Reason to raise this question is; the moment we move out of SQL/query land, speed issues start cropping up.

*Is there a known practice to deal with this kind of data effectively ?*

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia defines Big Data as "*Big data is a term for data sets that are so large or complex that traditional data processing applications are inadequate*". There are literally **dozens of definitions** of Big Data - http://www.forbes.com/sites/gilpress/2014/09/03/12-big-data-definitions-whats-yours, so I would advice you not to bother about the term itself and to rather look for the solution for your problem.

There is no silver bullet for choosing NoSQL/BigData solution - "horses for courses". To get started, take a look at the following research done by Altoros’s R&D engineers - "A Vendor-independent Comparison of NoSQL Databases: Cassandra, HBase, MongoDB, Riak ***with sharded MySQL***" - http://www.altoros.com/vendor_independent_comparison_of_nosql_databases.html. They have used "Yahoo Cloud Serving Benchmark" for benchmarking the various NoSQLs.